# Exception in LocalChangeInterceptor does not display white label error page

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I ran into an issue where exceptions thrown in LocaleChangeInterceptor display a blank page instead of the white label error page.

Given the following spring-boot application (I tried both 1.2.5 and 1.3.0.M2)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class LocaleChangeErrorDemoApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @RequestMapping("/show-locale")
    @ResponseBody
    public String showLocale(Locale locale) {
        return "locale: " + locale.toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/show-error")
    public void showError() {
        throw new RuntimeException("intentional error");
    }

    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(){
        return new CookieLocaleResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LocaleChangeErrorDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I call `http://localhost:8080/show-error` I see the spring-boot white label error page with my error as expected.

However, when I provoke an exception in LocaleChangeInterceptor by providing an illegal locale `http://localhost:8080/show-locale?locale=.` the page remains blank and the expected exception ("java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Locale part "." contains invalid characters") is only logged to the console.

Shouldn't the second case also display the white label error page?

Answer (score 0):

I run in the same issue just 2 days ago while running a test for web site security, this happens also in plain Spring MVC.

Looks like the error happens outside of what can be trapped by the exception resolver, so error pages are not used, I suppose this is the same in spring boot and its "white label error page".

When I saw it I was surprised but then I thought that I am probably not interested in handling the case of an user sending a completely invalid locale, why should happen ?

However if you want to handle this case you should probably write and register your own version of LocaleChangeInterceptor  that traps and ignores the exception of StringUtils.parseLocaleString that is not trapped in the [original code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.java#LocaleChangeInterceptor.preHandle%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I solved my problem by adding a filter at highest precedence and create error response manually to make sure any other such uncaught exceptions don't cause similar problems.